# PC sync software for android 2.2 phone (samsung I5801) using bluetooth

Tags: sync, android, mobile-phone

Is there any free or opensource software for synchronizing (sending/creating sms, creating/editing calender events, add/edit contacts etc.etc.) your android phone with windows xp (sp 2 or later) using bluetooth on your computer?

I use a samsung phone (I5801) having android v2.1 eclair in it.

I have used samsung kies but it supports only usb connection mode and is very heavy on system resources too.

While searching for such application I came across this application named **[The missing sync for android](http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html)**, which is exactly what I wanted but it is a paid one (not even a try version is available).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after so many days.

The best in the class software.   [**MyPhoneExplorer**](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/downloads.php).

Earlier it was only for Sony Ericsson's phone but now it supports android phones too. Great software that syncs most of the things (sms'es, calendars, to-dos).

You will need to install the **client software** on your android device and it will work through that client software.